# Why isn't my picture shown on my website when I am running my main.py-file? (It is working when I'm running my html-file)

Tags: python, html, image, flask, web

I wrote an HTML file, and it should show a picture. The HTML file is in an template folder, the picture is stored in the same folder. The main.py-file is not in this folder. I am using Bootstrap for the HTML file.
When I'm running the HTML itself, the picture is shown! But when I'm running the main method (in which the HTML file is rendered) the picture isn't shown :( The main method is written in Flask/python code.
Does anyone know why?

The main Code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, session, redirect

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="./templates")

@app.route('/detailseite', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def detailseite():
    return render_template('detailseite.html', Liste=list.columns.values)
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Weiterleitung</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13"
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <img src= "bild.png" alt="The picure cannot be shown" class="img-fluid">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check your browser log. It looks like your application does not serve the image when requested. You need to implement that functionality

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory **static** and insert the image **bild.png** file there

```
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="./templates", static_url_path='', 
            static_folder='./static')
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it doesn't work as well, but thank you!